# MySQL найти минимальное значение времени за каждый день для каждого пользователя

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица (user_name, time). Где поле time представлено в виде даты UNIX 2017-10-31 00:00:00
Нужно для каждого пользователя найти минимальное значение времени за каждый день.
Мне удалось получить нужное только за одну дату:

`SELECT user_name,
MIN(time) AS FirstTime
FROM table
WHERE  (time>= SUBDATE('2017-10-31 00:00:00',1))
AND (time<= SUBDATE('2017-10-31 23:59:59',1)) 
GROUP BY user_name`

На данный момент мне приходится использовать UNION столько раз-сколько дней мне нужно получить.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете группировать по выражению. Например, по дате от datetime.

```
SELECT user_name, date(time),
MIN(time) AS FirstTime
FROM table
WHERE  (time>= '2017-10-01 00:00:00')
AND (time<= '2017-10-31 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY user_name, date(time)
```

Comment: Только поле `date(time)` в выходном наборе зачем? те же данные есть и в поле `MIN(time)`...

Comment: если не нужно - можно убрать :)

Comment: речь не о том, нужно или не нужно. Речь о том, что одни и те же данные присутствуют в выходном наборе дважды. Это бывает оправдано, конечно, но весьма нечасто... На полноту и полезность Вашего ответа это никак не влияет.

Comment: Используя ваш пример мне не удалось добиться нужного результата. Возможно вы не так меня поняли или я вас. Запрос в моем посте выводит нужные данные за указанную дату, в тоже время запрос построенный на вашем примере показывает не то что мне нужно. Возможно я не правильно задала условие " не за каждый день" а за указанный промежуток скажем 3,5 или 7 дней

Comment: @Alisa ну добавьте условие на дату. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

я нашел решение в таком запросе, может кому пригодится. в поле TimeVal у меня заносятся и дата и время (2019-08-02 07:46:09.000)

```
select t.id, min(t.TimeVal) as FirstTime 
from table t
where t.id = 201 and MONTH(t.TimeVal)=8 -- тут в условии указываю за какой месяц нужна выборка (сейчас август указан) и id сотрудника, но это можно и убрать
group by id, day(p.TimeVal)
```